# C# How can I repeat a block of code when any button is pressed?

Tags: c#

Alright so I’m a beginner C# programmer and I’ve been writing (mostly) useless programs to get the hang of the language. The program that I’ve been working on creates a fake identity for you but I can’t figure out how to repeat the entire thing upon a button press. It wouldn’t have to be a specific button just a way to repeat the code without completely restarting the console. It seems like this would have a pretty straightforward answer but I can’t find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

The code I’m trying to repeat:

```
using System;

namespace False_Identity_Generator
{


    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random numgen = new Random();
            int first = 0;
       int last = 0;               // 1      2       3       4         5        6       7       8      9      10         11         12        13           14          15          16        17       18     19      20       21     22      23      24          25
        int age = 0;
        string[] firstnames = { "Bob", "Jeff", "Cary", "Shawn", "Logchad", "Sam", "Ogga", "Tree", "Sup", "Hammy", "Bologna", "Tostito", "Beulah", "Huckleberry", "Bailey", "Catamaran", "X-34", "Chadd", "Ben", "Benny", "Elon", "Baby", "Don", "Shelly", "Joben"};
                               //   1            2           3        4      5        6          7           8         9        10      11      12       13        14      15       16          17        18      19       20        21       22         23         24          25
        string[] lastnames = { "Liverson", "Chadderson", "Wright", "Lee", "Gamer", "Booga", "Liberdend", "Fractor", "Faker", "Baker", "Fox", "Wulf", "Sanders", "Bezos", "Musk", "Boatmen", "Baldhead", "Smad", "Sock", "Mobtown", "Shuck", "Snek", "McDonalds", "Wendys", "Waaaaaaaake"};
            first = numgen.Next(0, 26);
        last = numgen.Next(0, 26);
            Console.WriteLine("Your fake name is: " + firstnames[first] + " " + lastnames[last]);
        age = numgen.Next(1, 136);
        Console.WriteLine(" And your fake age is: " + age + " years old");
        Console.ReadKey();
        
        }

    }
```

Comment: You might want to look for "loops".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic way of doing what you want:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var DoContinue = true;
    
    while(DoContinue)
    {
        // Here place the code you wish to repeat

        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to continue? Y/N");
        var Answer = Console.ReadLine();
        DoContinue = Answer.ToUpper() == "Y";
    }
}
```

which in your case would give:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var DoContinue = true;
    string[] FirstNames = { "Bob", "Jeff", "Cary", "Shawn", "Logchad", "Sam", "Ogga", "Tree", "Sup", "Hammy", "Bologna", "Tostito", "Beulah", "Huckleberry", "Bailey", "Catamaran", "X-34", "Chadd", "Ben", "Benny", "Elon", "Baby", "Don", "Shelly", "Joben" };
    string[] LastNames = { "Liverson", "Chadderson", "Wright", "Lee", "Gamer", "Booga", "Liberdend", "Fractor", "Faker", "Baker", "Fox", "Wulf", "Sanders", "Bezos", "Musk", "Boatmen", "Baldhead", "Smad", "Sock", "Mobtown", "Shuck", "Snek", "McDonalds", "Wendys", "Waaaaaaaake" };
    var Rnd = new Random();
    int FirstNameIndex;
    int LastNameIndex;
    int Age;
    
    while(DoContinue)
    {
        FirstNameIndex = Rnd.Next(0, FirstNames.Length);
        LastNameIndex = Rnd.Next(0, LastNames.Length);
        Age = Rnd.Next(1, 136);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Your fake name is: {FirstNames[FirstNameIndex]} {LastNames[LastNameIndex]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"And your fake age is: {Age} year{(Age == 1 ? "" : "s")} old");
        
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to continue? Y/N");
        var Answer = Console.ReadLine();
        DoContinue = Answer.ToUpper() == "Y";
    }
}
```